# How do I have something happen *after* the scriptaculous highlight effect

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, scriptaculous

```
render :update do |page|
  page.visual_effect :highlight, row_id, :duration => 20, :startcolor => "#FFCC33", :restorecolor =>""
  page << "alert('hi');"
end
```

In the above code, I have a highlight effect that occurs and lasts for 20 seconds, after the highlight effect completes, I want to have an alert popup. Currently, the alert immediately pops up without waiting for the highlight effect to complete.

Comment: I'm not familiar enough with rails to comment, but if you change the alert code to `page << "setTimeout('alert(\'hi\')',20)"` does that have the desired effect?

Comment: That probably should solve the problem

Comment: Yup, perfect! If you submit it as an answer I'll choose it and close the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work for you:

```
render :update do |page|
  page.visual_effect :highlight, row_id, :afterfinish => "alert('hi')", :duration => 20, :startcolor => "#FFCC33", :restorecolor =>""
end
```

In pure JavaScript code, this effect can be applied as follows:

```
$('element_id').highlight({
    duration:20,
    startcolor: "FFCC33",
    afterFinish:function(){
        // do whatever you want
    }
})
```